# Mod Security - Body Request Length Too Long?

Tags: apache, mod-security, dedicated-server

I have a file uploading site and am getting this error when trying to upload files larger than 400MB. Does anyone know where I can set this value? I also have ModSecurity Disabled for this account so I don't know why MS is catching this in the first place!

"Request body (Content-Length) is larger than the configured limit" - Anyone know where I can change the configuration limit?

Thank you

Comment: What server? Also, this is off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

You need to increase the value for `LimitRequestBody` directive.

Setting it to `2147483647` (2GB) means 'unlimited'.

For details on this directive please read here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody